# Impossible to set minDate or maxDate in jquery-simple-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Here is the lib that i'm using : http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker

With the following fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3SNEq/2/, the datetime picker is well set for the minDate or MaxDate when setting up these datas directly in the appendDtpicker method.

But by using handleDtpicker like :

`$('#datetimepicker').handleDtpicker({ minDate: '2014/07/02' });`

I have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Is there any solution to set a min or a max date ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html#manual-handling_method-names) for `handleDtpicker`? There is no such option to set `minDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the minDate like you set the maxDate ([JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/kyy5B/)):

```
$('#datetimepicker').appendDtpicker({
        maxDate : '2014/07/19',
        minDate: '2014/07/02'        
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

To re-specify the min and max date sometime after page loaded, try to do something like this ([JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNEq/8/)):

```
$('.toRestrictDate').click(function()
{
    $('#datetimepicker').handleDtpicker('destroy');
    $('#datetimepicker').appendDtpicker({
        maxDate : '2014/07/13',
        minDate: '2014/07/8'        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i set a maxDate, in a second time, after have created an instance of this datetimepicker ?

Comment: I was trying some code to do that and I wasn't getting that because a little mistake mine, sorry. Check my answer updated please, I think is that what you want